# Infinite scroll back button without .pushstate

Tags: jquery, html, infinite-scroll

I have a website that uses an infinite scrolling system to load all my posts. All is well except for in Chrome and sometimes Firefox when a user clicks a post, and then clicks the back button, the page is completely reloaded from the top and doesn't bother to scroll down to the users last position. I've looked into a few solutions one being to implement a `.pushState` system for updating the url, but want to save that as a last resort.

I've noticed that websites like  http://imgur.com and http://buzzfeed.com both implement an infinite scrolling system, but when the user clicks a post then clicks the back button it'll return them to their last position without updating the url with the `.pushState`. How do they do it? Thanks, Julian

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with salient points based on the repo below.

1. We implement `pushState` and push in with a unique `uuid` to the window history object.
2. `window.history.state.uuid` is now available as something we can query.
3. Right before route change we can get the current `window.scrollY`, store that in a cache by `uuid`.
4. Also on route change (`onpopstate`), we can query our cache with the current `window.state.uuid`, retrieve the `scrollY` position and call `window.scrollTo(scrollY)`.

https://github.com/DockYard/ember-router-scroll